# Symfony inherited templates not rendering

Tags: php, symfony, templates, rendering

In my Symfony application, there are two templates - `showList.html.twig` and `add_user_form.html.twig` inheriting from the template `base.html.twig`. The base template gets rendered but not the other templates.

showList.html.twig

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}
{% block showList %}
<h1>Hello there!</h1>
<p>You have requested a list of all users.</p>
<p>There you go.</p>

</br>
{% if message %}
    <h1>{{ message }}</h1
{% endif %}

<table class="table table-striped">
    <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Email address</th>
    </tr>
    {% for user in usersArray %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ user.getId }}</td>
            <td>{{ user.getName }}</td>
            <td>{{ user.getEmailadresse }}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>

<button class="btn">
    <a href="{{ path('add_user_form') }}">Add user</a>
</button>
{% endblock %}
```

base.html.twig

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>{% block title %}Welcome!{% endblock %}</title>
        <link rel="icon" href="data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns=%22http://www.w3.org/2000/svg%22 viewBox=%220 0 128 128%22><text y=%221.2em%22 font-size=%2296%22>⚫️</text><text y=%221.3em%22 x=%220.2em%22 font-size=%2276%22 fill=%22%23fff%22>sf</text></svg>">
        {% block stylesheets %}
            <!-- Copy CSS from https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction/#css -->
            <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
        {% endblock %}
        {% block importmap %}{{ importmap('app') }}{% endblock %}
    </head>
    <body>
        {% block body %}{% endblock %}
        <h1>From base template</h1>
        {% block javascripts %}
            <!-- Copy JavaScript from https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction/#js -->
            <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cVKIPhGWiC2Al4u+LWgxfKTRIcfu0JTxR+EQDz/bgldoEyl4H0zUF0QKbrJ0EcQF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        {% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

The controller method looks like this:

```
    #[Route('/listUsers', name: 'list_users')]
    public function listUsers(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager): Response
    {
        $users = $entityManager->getRepository(User::class)->findAll();

        return $this->render('user/showList.html.twig', [
            'usersArray' => $users,
            'message' => 'Users fetched from database'
        ]);
    }
```

If I am not inheriting the templates, they get rendered fine.

Comment: I don't see any `{% block showList %}` in base template. Do you see it? Maybe you show use `{% block body %}` in __showList__?

Comment: The top-level blocks in child templates need to be defined in the parent.

Comment: Thank you. That solved my problem. Could someone post that as an answer so I can accept it?